# How much can I pack into this Raspberry Pi project?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've seen a lot of projects, tutorials and how-to's on the web regarding the Raspberry Pi.
I've just received my first Pi in the mail, and I can't wait to get tinkering with it.
Of course, doing any of these things is going to be a difficult process, however, as my experience with the Pi is next to none, I wondered about the capabilities of what I want to do with my first major project.
I'd like to be able to build an on-board computer for my car. I've seen several projects regarding this, and I've seen some good guides online.
However, none that I have seen will do EVERYTHING that I can think of....
I'm assuming that my 8GB SD card will be limited to only a selection of these specifications, however, here's a list of what I'd like the solution to be capable of, and if anyone knows any reason why this isn't possible, please give me a heads up :)

So...

- I'd like a front-end GUI (on a 7" touchscreen monitor) with a menu to navigate the options, which will include
  From this menu, I'd like to be able to select (and of course, run) the following:
- Media center (I've seen things like XBMC etc.) - I'd like this to be capable of taking over the radio unit and playign mp3's etc (possibly from my iphone!?)
- GPS/SatNav - I don't know how possible this is and I assume i'd need a 3G card or something...
- Reverse parking camera (stick a webcam in the rear view window) etc (I've seen good tutorials for this)
- Connect my phone with a bluetooth thingy(?) so that I can add a USB mic and play the receiver audio through my speakers (acting as a hands free kit)

I'll add more ideas too...

I'm not questioning if each of these individual specifications are possible, I am asking if they are all possible through one solution as a whole, with a GUI to navigate through them?

Thanks for any help.
Cal.

Comment: This is too broad a topic for stack overflow.com; we're not a discussion forum. If you run into trouble when trying to implement a specific solution, feel free to post a question that fits within our community guidelines. If needed, you can review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to understand what is on topic, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask to understand what should not be asked.

Comment: Apologies, I know there are other Pi forums and stuff but this is just the first place I came to, and I'm already registered here - plus it gets quite high up Google searches. Feel free to remove the post, I've got the response I was looking for.

Comment: @Cal hey, did you add the parking guidelines in the reverse parking camera? I am working on a project where I need to show the parking guidelines and rotate them based on the steering wheel angle input. Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all possible, all in one bundle. 8gb is more than enough for everything, it'll only limit your music collection. The only question is: how much work are you able/capable of doing. That will be the limiting factor, not your Pi.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, all exist and the pi can handle it.  But you'll be writing a lot of custom software to make them interoperate.